# Tiagra 4700 Compatible Chainrings

Tags: chainring

I'm looking for some replacement chainrings for a Shimano Tiagra 4700 50.34T 10 speed.

I'd like to keep the same ratio and same or similar tier of parts.

So far I haven't found any close matches by searching the internet. I'm getting a lot of chain sets and cranks coming up though.

Is there a generic type of replacement chainring available for the above specs that's compatible with my cranks? Is there a search term that I might have some luck with? Is there a shimano part available for sale that is designed as a drop-in replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have anything too useful to say about mix and matching with the various 4-bolt asymmetric Shimano chainrings. Even if the function is okay with some or many permutations, the looks never will be because the 3d contours won't be right.

But, there most certainly are designated chainrings that are replacements. To find them, go to si.shimano.com and find the exploded view diagram for the crank model. There is a list of part numbers there that show you the options. Typically most sellers will list the part numbers alongside other info.

Generally speaking, Shimano is no longer designing their product line to allow one outer chainring to be a replacement for more than one model of crank, at least cosmetically. Among inners there is still some interchangeability.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Various manufacturers make aftermarket replacement rings for the Shimano 4-bolt pattern.

Spécialités T.A. spring to mind as one. The rings are classic flat style and so to blend in to the 3D contours they offer bolt sets to finish the 3D shape of the cranks nicely. They are not the only company to do this and Shimano themselves use (or used to use) a very similar system with the 4-arm cyclocross chainsets (46-36t) which are generally also classic flat rings.

You should be able to get parts that match. I have used the special nut kit on a chainset it wasn't meant for -- the difference isn't massive between most of them but if you want a perfect finish, get the correct bolts. The old 105 5800 may be closest match in shape.

Example images

[image]
[image]
[image]